# How to check if an image exists based on the alt attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I want to append another image to this list.

```
<img src="1.jpg" alt="apple">
```

If `apple` already in this list, then do nothing.  Is there a way I can use jQuery to check?

I tried to use find,  `var existItem = $("#targetBox").find(" not sure what to put here ")`

```
<div id="test">
  <img src="1.jpg" alt="apple">
  <img src="2.jpg" alt="banana">
  <img src="3.jpg" alt="grape">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use the following to check if there *exists* such an image:

```
if ($("#test img[alt='apple']").length) {
}
```

And then, to add another image:

```
$("<img>").attr("src", "4.jpg").attr("alt", "orange").appendTo("#test");
```

Comment: it works, however, if I am using variable, then it stops working. var a = 'apple'; if ($("img.targetItemImage[alt = a]").length)

Comment: @feelexit: You have to concatenate its value: `if ($("img.targetItemImage[alt ='" + a + "']").length)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's attribute selectors for this -

```
if ($("#targetBox").find("img[alt='THE_NEW_IMAGE_ALT']").length){

}
```

This code looks for images that have an `alt` attribute equal to `THE_NEW_IMAGE_ALT`.  It checks to see if the results are empty (checking the length).  If no elements are returned (length=0) then there is no other image with that same `alt` parameter.

You can use this same code for testing any value of any attribute.  For example, if you wanted to test the existence of an image based upon the `src` attribute you would simply change the selector to look like this - `find("img[src='THE_IMAGE_SRC']")`

References -

- [jQuery attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)